# Let $f$ be defined on $(z,\infty)$ with $f'$ going to $0$. Does $t^{-1}f(t)$ goes to $0$?

Tags: integration, limits, derivatives

Let $f$ be defined on $(z,\infty)$ with derivative $f'$ and $\lim_{t \to \infty} f'(t) = 0$.

Then does it follow that $t^{-1}f(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$?

For context, I'm not understanding the below proof, so I'm looking for an alternative explanation.

[image]

And here is the added context.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: "I'm looking for an alternative explanation" I would try using the mean value theorem: $f(t) = f(t_*) + f'(c_t)(t-t_*)$ for some $c_t \in (t_*,t)$. The condition you have allows you to pick $t_*$ large enough such that $f'(c_t)$ is as small as you like.

Comment: @Winther but then how do you control $f(t_*)$?

Comment: $f(t_*)/t$ can be made small by just taking $t$ large enough. You fix $t_*$ by the requirement that the derivative has become small enough and you then take $t$ large enough to ensure this term is small enough.